# Why do we need to put let in front of a function in a list

Tags: haskell, syntax, let

This is the original function

```
[let square x = x * x in (square 5, square 3, square 2)]
```

I tried to remove let from the line above, but it doesn't work.

```
[square x = x * x in (square 5, square 3, square 2)]

<interactive>:21:11: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
```

Why let is necessary to be there?

Comment: That's the syntax. Maybe you just want `[x * x | x <- [5, 3, 2]]`.

Comment: Note that if you wanted a list with 3 elements (rather than a list containing a single 3-element tuple), you should've written `let square x = x * x in [square 5, square 3, square 2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List is created from *expressions*. Expression for introduction local variable name should start with `let` (or, more specifically, should use `let ... in` syntax). `square x = x * x` is a top-level function declaration.